# Understanding interrupt-controller in Linux kernel device tree

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, interrupt, armv8

The Linux kernel device tree can specify the address of an interrupt controller like this:

```dts
interrupt-controller {
    compatible = "arm,cortex-a15-gic";
    interrupt-parent = <0x38>;
    #interrupt-cells = <0x3>;
    interrupt-controller;
    reg = <0x0 0x50041000 0x0 0x1000 0x0 0x50042000 0x0 0x100>;
    status = "okay";
    linux,phandle = <0x38>;
    phandle = <0x38>;
};
```

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/interrupts.txt seems outdated, it doesn't mention what it means when `#interrupt-cells = <0x3>;`, so I don't know for example what `0x0 0x50041000 0x0` means.

Also, what does `status`, `linux, phandle`, `phandle` and `interrupt-parent` mean?

I want to add support for virtualization on a Jetson Nano board, and I must know which interrupts to add to the device tree, as well as how to translate them to the device three `interrupt-controller` node.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/refs/tags/android-10.0.0_r0.20/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/interrupt-controller/arm%2Cgic.txt

Comment: @oakad thanks, this makes some concepts clearer, but where do those numbers come from? I tried finding it through ARM manuals and couldn't fing any good descrption about all this vgic thing

Comment: They come from many places: how the SOC is wired internally and configured, how the board is wired, what the driver expects to see. Designing an OF device tree for a new board is not the easiest of tasks. :-)

Comment: @oakad given that the board is an Nvidia Jetson Nano, how would you find this? I've been googling all day and only found the right numbers because someone already had made a tutorial on how to recompile the kernel with KVM support, but I don't know where he got the numbers from

Comment: https://developer.arm.com/architectures/system-architectures/system-components/arm-generic-interrupt-controller

Comment: If it's a ready made board, you just expect the board designer to supply you the OF file and use it as is, no changes.

Comment: @oakad but they didn't. The board comes with no KVM support. Some people made the device tree and recompiled the kernel with KVM support

Comment: Then file a bug / request to the vendor of your board.